# Liberar conexão não segura com Websocket

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, pwa

Boa tarde,

Hoje possuimos um sistema em PWA (https) que precisa realizar a conexão não segura com um aplicativo embarcado, o mesmo com ip proprio.

Gostaria de saber se essa comunicação é possivel e como eu poderia estar configurando isso. Já que buscando na internet não encontro nenhuma informação sobre isso.

Tentamos colocar um certificado self-signed no lado do embarcado, mas estamos recebendo esse erro "Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID".

Alguem poderia ajudar com isso?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Caro Lucas nas respostas linkadas acima é informado que somente com conexão segura. Essa é a proposta do PWA, ao contrário disto não seria valido e nem seguro e seria um problema pra proposta.

Answer (score 1):

Se você utiliza https na web, é obrigatório que todos as demais conexões sejam seguras. Não há como contornar o problema do self-signed, já que o PWA não vai permitir tal comunicação.

Uma solução que eu vejo é usar um domínio público pra aplicação e gerar um certificado válido pra ele (Lets Encrypt, por exemplo). A aplicação embarcada precisaria de um IP fixo pra resolver corretamente o DNS (ou um DDNS), não sei se isso é possível no escopo do seu projeto porém resolveria seu problema de certificado.

Exemplo:
PWA fica em https://app.examplo.com.br
Embarcado em https://device123.intranet.examplo.com.br

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, mas o problema está que o embarcado sobe a propria rede WI-FI onde eu conecto para realizar as comunicações. Vou validar se é possivel efetuar alguma configuração DNS